# Update date now in React hook

Tags: reactjs, date, react-hooks, react-state

I need to create a custom hook that updates the current time on click

```
export const useNow = (): [number, VoidFunction] => {
  const [now, setNow] = React.useState(Date.now())
  const update = () => {
    const newDate = new Date(now)
    setNow(Date.parse(newDate.getTime().toString()))
  }
  return [now, update]
}
```

The problem is that whenever the `update` method is invoked the `now` state is always updated with the same value.

How can I correctly set `now` with the current timestamp?

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Each time the `update` method is invoked, the `now` state is updated with the `Date.now()` timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for `now` not updating is that `new Date(now)` creates a new date instance with the default state `Date.now()` that has been provided at the top of the component.

Creating a `new Date()` during update should resolve your problem.

```
import React from "react";

export const useNow = (): [number, VoidFunction] => {
  const [now, setNow] = React.useState<number>(new Date().getTime());

  const update = () => {
    setNow(new Date().getTime());
  };

  return [now, update];
};
```

Comment: It doesn't resolve

Comment: I made an edit, how about now?

Comment: The state is updated with `NaN`

Comment: @AntonioSantoro How about now?

Comment: Now it is updated, however when I invoke the hook from a component, the `now` value is always the initial one

Comment: That's the point of states, now represents the last updated value.

Comment: That's the problem, from my component I'm not getting the updated value

Comment: How do you use the `useNow` hook?

Comment: By invoking `const [now] = useNow()` from my component

Comment: Wouldn't it be `const [now, update] = useNow()`? And initially when you create the hook it should be the current time but if you want to update simply use `update()`.

Comment: It's the same, the `update` function is invoked from another component, the read `now` value is always the initial one and not the updated one

Comment: remember  @AntonioSantoro that each component has their own version of `useNow` state, unless they rely on the return from the same hook call. if you want the same state independent of call, you need to use context or use a store from a third party library.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition, note that you can automate the updates with `setInterval`:

```js
function useNow(refreshFrequency: number): Date {
    const [now, setNow] = useState(new Date);
    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(
            () => setNow(new Date()),
            refreshFrequency,
        );
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    });
    return now;
}
```

You can then simply use it with `const now = useNow();` in a component.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [qsantos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76814285/6236042), I took a slightly different approach.

Instead of the hook updating every *x* ticks, the following allows the hook to update whenever the time has changed by *x units*.

The distinction between these two different approaches can be useful in certain situations, for example, if you're displaying a clock and want a somewhat accurate reflection of the current time.

```
type UnitOfTime = "year" | "month" | "date" | "hour" | "minute" | "second" | "millisecond";

function getDatePart(date: Date, part: UnitOfTime) {
  switch (part) {
    case "year":
      return date.getFullYear();
    case "month":
      return date.getMonth();
    case "date":
      return date.getDate();
    case "hour":
      return date.getHours();
    case "minute":
      return date.getMinutes();
    case "second":
      return date.getSeconds();
    case "millisecond":
      return date.getMilliseconds();
  }
}

function useNow(frequency: number, unit: UnitOfTime) {
  const [now, setNow] = useState(new Date());

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const newNow = new Date();
      const diff = Math.abs(getDatePart(newNow, unit) - getDatePart(now, unit));
      if (diff >= frequency) {
        setNow(newNow);
      }
    }, 1);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  });

  return now;
}
```

Example difference between this and the linked answer:

Consider your hook is called at 11:59, and you want it to update every hour. With the linked answer, the hook would update the time at 12:59, whereas this solution would update the time at 12:00.

---

Disclaimers:

- Running a `setInterval` every tick may have a negative impact, but from my limited testing it seems to work fine with no noticeable performance hit.
- I've done minimal testing on this, but it seems to work as intended